# Where should I look for details about 'access denied' errors?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security, permissions

This question derives from [Deploying a new database on a new server, an msbuild ssdt rookie issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16700374/684646).

Since I have a `permission denied` error, I expect to find which user is failing to access so I can grant it.

Is there a place in the Event Viewer (Windows 7) where I can look for it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to look in SQL Server's error log, which is kind of a catch-22, since you need access to the SQL Server in order to see the error log.

[image]

[image]

You don't need direct access to SQL Server to read the log; if you have physical access to the machine, you can find the log in something like:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL2012\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
```

Right-click, open with Notepad, and scroll to the bottom, you'll see things like:

> 2013-05-23 16:34:56.29 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
>   2013-05-23 16:34:56.29 Logon       Login failed for user 'whatever'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]

This is, of course, for security purposes. Similar to the reason why these details are not revealed to the end user when they hit the login failure.

Comment: The OP posted he has a "Permission Denied" error. Not a "Login Failed" error. This answer doesn't answer the question. How do you find actual permission denied errors for users who are able to login to the server but unable to perform certain tasks on the SQL server?

Comment: @AaronBertrand  you say there is no permission denied error in SQL Server but one of our users is getting ""The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object xxx" and even though that user has permission on that database it would be good to see in the logs more details, but i cant find anything

Comment: @AaronBertrand the user receiving the error isn't listed in the error message.  The user i think they are logged in as does have permission to execute the stored procedure but it keeps saying permission denied, so if they were logged in as a different user then that would be useful info to have in the log.   Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look in the windows event log, under Application. It will often provide additional depth to the SQL Server error log and can give specific drive/folder information on what was denied. If you don't have administrative tools installed here is how to add them [Display Administrative tools Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700232.aspx)